# Passing data to second page in an async function

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a two page flutter application I'm pushing some data to the second page from my first page.

I have also a `Future` in the first page which should be able to change the data in the second page when it got fulfilled.

Following is a sample code from my application.

```
String _text = "From screen one";
ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera).then((image) {
  _text = "got image";
});
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 600), () {
  //StateContainer.of(context).updateStatus(Status.loading);
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage(text: _text)),
  );
});

/// My second page
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  String text;
  SecondPage({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
            child: Text(
              this.text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

My question is it's not showing `got image` in the second page. How I can show it?

Comment: and your question is ...?

Comment: @pskink - it's not showing `got image` in the second page.

Comment: pass `ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)` to the second page, not `_text` and use `FutureBuilder`

Comment: So you're trying to play with a race condition here? Why would you want to code that way? Why not simply await the image response and then push the route? Or push the route in the `.then` of the future.

Comment: @ishaan - it is taking some time to show my second page, I want to show the second page seamlessly. And also how there is a race condition here?

Comment: `"I want to show the second page seamlessly."` so pass the `Future` and use `FutureBuilder` in your second page

Comment: @pskink - let me try that, thanks!

Comment: and of course remove that `Future.delayed`

Comment: @pskink - If I remove `Future.delayed` it will show the second page before camera preview window appears so I added the `Future.delayed`.  I there any other way to handle it?

Comment: @pskink - As you suggested `FutureBuilder` is working fine, can you add it as answer to this question?

Comment: add a self answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) in the comments following code working for me.

```
final Future promise = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
 Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage(promise: promise,)),
  );

/// My second page
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future promise;
  SecondPage({Key key, @required this.promise}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: this.promise,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                print(snapshot.data);
                return Text('Hello ');
              }
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```